# Repeat R script multiple times

Tags: r, iteration, repeat, lapply

I have an R script with hundreds of lines. This script eventually gives me a single numerical answer at the end. Now I want to create a confidence interval and hence run this whole script over and over multiple times to be able to calculate the mean and standard deviation. But I do not want to create a 'for' loop over the whole thing because that becomes really complicated

After some research, I came across this method:

My final answer is named as 'result' and then in a new script file,

```
result_list<-lapply(1:10, function(n)source("my_script_file.R"))
result_list
```

(repeating 10 times for example)

However the final results looks like this,

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$value
[1] 136.9876

[[1]]$visible
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[[2]]$value
[1] 138.4969

[[2]]$visible
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[[3]]$value
[1] 0.2356484

[[3]]$visible
[1] TRUE

. 
.
```

Now I have no idea what the second line means in every iterations? And how do I get the list of values, `result_list$values` doesn't work, while also ignoring the too small values that could be simulation error as like the 3rd one in here to be able to calculate the mean and sd.

Also Is there any other way to repeat this process except this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `$value` to get the 'value' from each iteration

```
 lapply(1:10, function(n)source("my_script_file.R")$value)
```

As it is a single element, it may be also useful to use `sapply` to get a `vector` output

```
 v1 <- sapply(1:10, function(n)source("my_script_file.R")$value)
```

We can subset the `vector` for values greater than a particular threshold, for example 0.5,

```
 v1[v1 > 0.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making your script as a function, loading the function once, and then using `replicate` instead of `lapply(1:n, ...)`.

Here's a very simple example:

Imagine you were working with a simple R script file that had the following contents:

```
## saved in working directory as "testfun.R"
myFun <- function(x, y, z) {
  mean(rnorm(x)) + mean(rnorm(y)) + mean(rnorm(z))
}

myFun(10, 12, 14)
## End of "testfun.R" file
```

Now, compare the timings of having to `source` 100 times with having to simply run the function 100 times:

```
fun1 <- function(n = 10) replicate(n, myFun(10, 12, 14))
fun2 <- function(n = 10) lapply(1:n, function(x) source("testfun.R")$value)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(100), fun2(100), unlist(fun2(100)), times = 1)
## Unit: milliseconds
##               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##          fun1(100)  3.064384  3.064384  3.064384  3.064384  3.064384  3.064384     1
##          fun2(100) 59.635228 59.635228 59.635228 59.635228 59.635228 59.635228     1
##  unlist(fun2(100)) 61.349713 61.349713 61.349713 61.349713 61.349713 61.349713     1
```

I'm not sure how much of a difference it would make in the long run if more of the time is taken up in processing (rather than reading the source file), but I would still consider a function + `replicate` as a cleaner and easier-to-read alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But the issue here is I already have multiple loops and functions in my R script, so incorporating all that in one new function would require a lot of changes and editing and make it more complex.

Comment: @mac, I don't see why that would be a problem. Just wrap the entire thing in a function. It shouldn't require any more complexity than that....

Comment: hmm let me give it a try. But there are so many variables throughout, I would need to include them all in my new function (right?). 
And I understand your suggested method is quite quicker as seen above, but its not much an issue in my case. But nevertheless, I still want to try it. I am still in the learning phase of R. So thanks again. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @mac, no. See, for example, how I wrote `fun1()` and `fun2()` in my benchmarking step. I just added one argument that takes the number of iterations I want to do. Note that to use `fun1()`, I would have had to have sourced the `"testfun.R"` file to begin with.